# How to run allure generate command while using aws code build

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytest, allure

I am using aws codebuild to execute my testsuite. It says 'permission denied' when I try to run allure genrate in aws code build.

Pleas share the solution if anyone knows on how to generate allure report while working with aws code build.

I am using pytest and the scenario is working fine in local. but failes in aws as aws build is not allowing me to run allure generate command.

on successful dev deployment -- > tetssuite execution -- > generate allure repors --> uploade them to s3 --> send the report via email using aws SNS with lambda.

all above steps are working fine, but the 3rd step.(allure generate).

Please share the solution if anyone knows how to do it.

Comment: Able to run the command now. But it gives below error now 

"Error: Could not find or load main class io.qameta.allure-result.CommandLine
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.qameta.allure-result.CommandLine"

If any one knows how to solve this issue please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this is by downloading allure package freshly outside of the $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR and set the path for the same location .
(Initially I made this part of test repository itself and add that location to PATH, which was not working)